# Apply active class with React Router 4 depending on the path

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have a menu on top of the page in my React + React Router application. How can I apply active class to my menu element when the route matches that element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Router 4 has that functionality built-in: the [`NavLink` component](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md).

> A special version of the <Link> that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL.

```
<NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/">
  Home
</NavLink>;
```